# Enter BIOS Setup on Lenovo G580

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have installed Windows 7 on my Lenovo G580 laptop.

To enable Intel Virtualisation Technology, I need to go to BIOS.

When I start my laptop, it displays press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter BIOS Setting, <kbd>F12</kbd> for Multi-Boot Menu.

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, instead of going to BIOS Settings, My laptop prompts for recovery of Windows 7.

Tried many ways by long pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, Combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, Installing BIOS Update, Nothing worked so far. I also tried pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> repeatedly and quickly immediately after turning on the laptop. It goes to the Windows 7 Recovery Screen.

Comment: This is probably a BIOS incompatibility between UEFI and Windows 7 . You need to remove hard disk and power up the laptop.

Answer (score 2):

My first recommendation would be to press the button tho the right of the power button, while the computer is shut off. I believe it should come up with a menu to be able to go into the BIOS setup. I have a Lenovo Y50-70 and my "Novo Button Menu" appears when I press it.

If that does not work, please check [this](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1470203.htm) guide. It may just be the way it boots, or you may have enabled the "fast boot up" option in BIOS, in which(from my experience) it would not let you go into your BIOS

Comment: @Anoop : Follow the lenovo link at bottom of that webpage. It should be of help.

Comment: That link is broken :(

Comment: well link http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht075709 is not broken, but is for authorized users only.

Answer (score 0):

Press ESC, that usually gives you a list of things you can boot into. Also, try DEL instead of F2 to get to BIOS. On my laptop, it is F12 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

1. Turn your computer off.
2. On the left hand side of your laptop next to the charger port. There is a small button.
3. Hold the small button until the Lenovo logo appears.
4. A small blue box with 4 options will appear on screen.
5. Choose the one that meets your requirements

Answer (score 0):

lenovo G580

1. power button
2. delete or f2 key
3. you will see "Boot Menu / App Menu"
4. press Tab key to switch to App Menu
5. Set up

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer for the reported problem, but this might help someone searching for missing Bios setup option.
In my case - message to enter Bios (F2) or boot options (F12) was missing because Windows was restoring from suspend thus it was impossible to get into Bios.
Restoring Windows and doing regulart restart fixed the missing Bios messages.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the same problem in Lenovo support which have something like below problem. :

**Symptom**

Customer installed Windows 7 64-bit and drivers. After the installation of intel hd graphics driver and laptop restart, Windows is unable to start normally. Windows will try to start the automatic startup recovery program (which is recommended by default). But this program will fail in resolving the problem. When Windows tries to start normally, it result in a blue screen. After windows restart, the boot menu is not showing through F12 key. F2 key for BIOS access is also not working.

**Affected configurations**

The symptom above may occur to the following systems:

G480/G580/G485/G585 without pre-installed OS

**Solution**

1. Try to remove the hard disk and do a reset by draining the power (press power button for 10 seconds without battery and AC adapter).
2. Try to enter bios using F2 key.

If you are successful in entering the bios, Load up Bios default settings by F8 key within BIOS. Connect the Hard drive back and check again if you are able to access BIOS by pressing F2 key.

If the steps above didn't fix the issue, Bios will need to be re-flashed.

Thank you !!

Comment: User Wup123 has already linked to the related documents(see my comment to OP). Kindly include the research link.